# Unable to connect to Database Engine or Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am making a website for my friends. Here I have made a sign up page and using 3-tier architecture in .Net framework.
For database I am using sql server management 2008 R2.

On filling up the details in the sign up page I get an error. I am unable to understand whether I am unable to connect database or server properly.

What authentication I should use? Windows or SQL server Authentication and what has to be put up in web.config file.

Here are the screen shots.

[image: Sign up page with error]

[image: The authentication that I am using to connect]

[image: web.config file appsetting tag]

My connectionString in DataLayerClass :

string strQuery = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["djconnect"].ToString();

djconnect is the key that I am using in the app setting tag.

Comment: use [ConnectionString Maker](http://www.ConnectionStrings.com)

Comment: Use SQL Server Authentication and a connection string with that information in.

Comment: for password can I leave it blank?

Answer (score -1):

Pass connection string directly into datalayerclass using sql connection instead of passing it to web config.